# В чем разница между битовыми операторами и обычными?

Tags: java, битовые-операции

Если раньше я видел битовые операции в чужом коде - я не мог понять, что этот код делает, так как не понимал работу этих операторов, теперь я разобрался и сейчас я не понимаю, в чем разница между таким кодом

```
boolean a = false;
boolean b = true;
if(a | b) {
    doSmth();
}
```

и таким

```
boolean a = false;
boolean b = true;
if(a || b) {
    doSmth();
}
```

Я слышал, что битовые операции используются для улучшения оптимизации, и если так, то в чем именно их преимущество?

Comment: Какой язык то хоть?

Comment: @Darth раз `boolean`, то скорее всего java

Comment: таки да, java, забыл указать, сорян

Comment: логические операторы могут применяться только к логическим операндам, битовые - не только

Comment: На мой взгляд, побитовые операции преимущественно стоит использовать для манипуляции с битами чисел, а логические операторы - для формирования `boolean` значения из нескольких условий.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Представим, что у вас есть переменная F типа byte, содержащий значение 0. 
В память он запишется как 00000000.
А теперь представим, что вам нужно хранить 8 логических флагов.
Вы конечно можете создать 8 булевых переменных, или даже целый массив, но рациональнее с т.з. памяти использовать битовые операции.

Вы можете использовать логические операции для проверки флагов, например F&1 вернет истину, если в крайней справа ячейке памяти находится значение 1.
Возможно так будет понятнее: 
00000001&000000001=1
00000000&000000001=0
Чтобы проверить установлен ли шестой слева флаг нужно выполнить операцию
00000000&00100000=0 или в коде F&32
В общем виде формула проверки i-го значения флага - F&(2^(i-1))

Такой подход к хранению флагов позволяет очень рационально использовать память не беспокоясь о возможных растратах на [выравнивание данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Кроме того операции побитового сдвига позволяют умножать и делить на два с большой скоростью.

Answer (score 1):

Канонический пример: `foo != null && foo.hasBar()` правая часть выражения не будет проверена при использовании `&&`.

Также, например, `|` может быть использован как побитовый оператор `ИЛИ` при работе с `byte`, `int` и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

"обычные" сравнивают выражения (если a верно или b верно, doSmth), в то время как битовые производят сравнения битов (101100 | 111001) -> (111101)

В твоем случае, битовое сравнение не имеет смысла. Сравнивают какие-либо числа.

Comment: Что значит "не имеет смысла"? Для `boolean` операндов действие операторов `&`, `|` и `^` определено. Вменяемый результат получить можно. Куда делся смысл?

Comment: Имеется в виду смысл практический. Я не говорил, что эта операция невозможна.